# File "main.py", line 14 if ctx.author.id == ВАШ АЙДИ: ^^^^^^^^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, бот, site

помогите

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import keep_alive

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('работает')

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == ВАШ АЙДИ:
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send("Ког загружен")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не создатель бота")

@client.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == ВАШ АЙДИ:
        client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send("Ког загружен")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не создатель бота")

@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == ВАШ АЙДИ:
        client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send("Ког загружен")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не создатель бота")

for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")

keep_alive.keep_alive()

my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']

# Подключение бота
client.run(os.environ.get('TOKEN'), bot=True, reconnect =True)
```

Ошибка: `File "main.py", line 14 if ctx.author.id == ВАШ АЙДИ: ^^^^^^^^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Ну вместо `ВАШ АЙДИ` надо подставить ваш конкретный `id` видимо ))

Comment: пробувал и ничего не изменилось

Comment: поменять надо во всех местах, а не в одном
а еще лучше питон поучить прежде, чем в ботов лезть

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно. Вместо `ВАШ АЙДИ` вы должны вставить Ваш Discord ID аккаунта.

Советую изучить Python, чтобы не задавать таких глупых вопросов.